# Popup to insert link in ClassicEditor not opening

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have a modal in my HTML page where I am using a ClassicEditor to input text and images. The popups to insert media and tables show up, but if I try inserting a link, it just stutters, and nothing appears to happen.

[image: Rich text editor in my modal]

This is the code for my modal. The ClassicEditor is the div with id="newsEditor"

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
                <h5 class="modal-title text-white">Ny/Endre nyhet</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                
                <form id="newsForm">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label>Tittel</label>
                        <input class="form-control" 
                               type="text"
                               id="newsTitle"/>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label>Kategori</label>
                        <select
                            class="form-select"
                            id="newsCategory"
                            asp-items="Model.NewsCategories">
                            <option value="-1">Velg en kategori</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <div id="newsEditor"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="newsSave">Lagre</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Lukk</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is how i implement it using JavaScript:

```
let newsEditor = document.getElementById("newsEditor");
let editor;

ClassicEditor
        .create(newsEditor, {
            ckfinder: {
                uploadUrl: "/api/attachment/uploadImage",
                options: {
                    resourceType: 'Images'
                }
            }
        })
        .then(newEditor => {
            editor = newEditor;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

I have managed to "dig up" the popup by adjusting the z-index, because it appears beneath the modal and backdrop. However, I haven't found a way to edit this using css. Also seems weird to me considering the other popup menus work just fine.